# Erro ao instalar Android SDK Tools

Tags: android

Estou obtendo um erro ao instalar o Android SDK Tools:

> Failed to rename directory C:\android-sdk-windows\tools to C:\android-sdk-windows\temp\ToolPackage.old01

O que é preciso fazer? Já desativei o antivírus e não funciona. E se eu paro o processo fechando o Android SDK Manager e depois abrindo ele de novo dá erro. Dizendo que não é possível localizar o `android.bat`.

Comment: Pelo erro eu creio que pode ser falta de permissão.......

Comment: Tenta baixar um novo instalador ou pacote (.zip).

Comment: Vai até a pasta indicada no caso o c:\android-sdk-windows\temp\ e delete todos os arquivos dentro dela, em seguida tente efetuar o download novamente, acho que seu erro deve ser a atualização do sdk tools